# Monospace Font: Increase textsize based on device size

Tags: android, xamarin, font-size, monospace

I have an app that must show a printing-screen preview for an zebra printer.
The data to be printed is pure-text and it there are a maximum of 80 characters in one line.

The preview is pure android: text views in a vertical linear layout, one text view per line and monospace font. The rendering works. For my phone i have set the font size to 7dp, and the 80 characters fit on the screen in portrait mode.

Now, is there a way to calculate the text size to fit exactly 80 characters on one line and being device size independant?

I tried the following to calculate the text size and text scale:

```
private void CalculateTextSizeAndScale(int numberOfChars, out float textSize, out float textScale)
{
    var text = new string('M', numberOfChars);
    var paint = new Paint
    {
        TextSize = 100f,
        TextScaleX = 1f
    };
    paint.SetTypeface(Typeface.Monospace);

    var width = paint.MeasureText(text);
    textSize = _screenWidth / width * 100f;

    paint.TextSize = textSize;
    paint.TextScaleX = 1f;

    width = paint.MeasureText(text);
    textScale = _screenWidth / width;
}
```

This seems correct for some screen resolution. It works perfectly for my android phone in portrait mode, but is totally wrong for landscape mode.

I use Display.GetMetrics to retrieve the screen width.

Here is a screen shot on my android phone

Portrait Phone
[image: portrait phone]

Landscape Phone
[image: landscape phone]

Now, on my tablet, it looks different

Portrait Tablet
[image: portrait tablet]

Landscape Tablet
[image: landscape tablet]

Comment: lets try to convert px to sp.sp=(px/1,5)*x. If i am correct px is screen width and x is a number that gives what you need for every resolution.try to find that x

Comment: to get px: var met = new DisplayMetrics();
disp.GetMetrics(met);
var widthm = met.WidthPixels;